# Android AIDL: How to get service instance in activity when service is in another process?

Tags: android, android-service, aidl

I have a service in my app which binds to the activity. The service however is in another process and I can't figure out how to get its instance in the activity. For services in same process I do it something like this

Inside `onServiceConnected`

```
public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
    Service.Binder binder = (MService.Binder) binder;
    //get service
    musicSrv = binder.getService();
```

In my `Service` class I have

```
public class Binder extends Binder {
        public Service getService() {
            return Service.this;
        }
    }
```

I have no clue how to do this in my case. I couldn't find any such examples online. Can someone please help me. Thanks !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't! It's not possible. Actually, that is the definition of "in another process", it means the instances can never have direct access to each other.

You can however define a inter-process communication for it using AIDL. Please check the AIDL guide on how to implement it

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html